# CSS dropdown menu opens while not even hovering over nav

Tags: css, safari

I made a pure css dropdown menu at https://dittekstbureau.dk.

It works perfectly well in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. After hovering over the nav bar to open the dropdown, and thereafter closing the dropdown again, it sometimes pops open again while moving the cursor around the page.

It does not always happen, but moving the cursor around the page under the nav makes it pop in here and there.

The bug seems to happen when the cursor moves across some space reserved for the links.

Anyone experienced anything like it?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I just fixed the problem.

Somehow setting pointer-events to "none" on the a-tags in the dropdown menu, while setting it to "auto" on hover, fixed the problem.

It seems that on Safari, when a div having pointer-events set to "none", the contents of that div still interact with pointer events sometimes. Not sure why, though.